# Interface methods - implementation vs. definition

Tags: java, interface

Please explain why the following isn't valid in Java (1.7).

Having an interface:

```
interface foo {
  mymethod(argument arg)
}
```

where `argument` also is an interface:

```
interface argument{}
```

an implementation of `argument`:

```
class someArgument implements argument{}
```

and an implementation of `foo`:

```
class bar implements foo {
  mymethod(someArgument arg) {}
}
```

The class `bar` results in compilation errors, since `mymethod` isn't implemented. Is there anyway to accomplish the above with out the need of casting?

Thanks!

Comment: It might be rubbish and late in the day.. but I would like to less specific of the type of argument in the interface definition... possible or not? :)

Comment: Only with generics. Overriding does not allow covariant parameter lists.

Comment: It's probably flawed design - i'll consider a different approach :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mymethod()` signature has to be **exact** as defined in the `foo` interface.

Suppose you have another class (`baz`) that implements `argument`. Then, the `mymethod(argument arg)` signature will allow passing parameters of the `baz` type.

But if you keep it like this:

```
class bar implements foo {
  mymethod(someArgument arg) {}
}
```

you will be not able to pass `baz` instances to `mymethod`, because you've broken the contract.

As a side note, you should follow [naming conventions](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html) when developing!

Comment: True. But my intention is to make a specifik implementation that takes only a specifik type so that casting is unnessescary... Using the (argument arg) I miss the "specific" implementation details for the passed argument (is it a baz or a someArgument)

Comment: You will have to implement the method from the interface, anyway. But you can overload it with another method, that takes a `someArgument` instance as a paramer. Unfortunatelly, this won't work also, because there will be ambiguity(JVM won't know which method to invoke when you pass `someArgument`). The only non-generic solution I can make up is by changing the name of the method and imeplementing your specific logic.

Comment: As commented above: it's more likely that this design approach is flawed and should not be pursued further :) I'll find a better solution (that compile)!